# Execute two methods on custom number of cores/thread for each method in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to specify the number of Cores/threads used for each method and without blocking them. 
Example: 
I have method A and method B.
The method A will be called 50 times, and method B also.

Let suppose I have  a CPU with 16 cores.
I would like to delegate that for method A it will use 2 threads in parallel and for method B 4 and without blocking them. 
I've tried with semaphores, but they are blocking and releasing after the task is executed.

Here is some sample code :
Note: threadService methods are just calling Thread.Sleep for 3 secs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadService threadService = new ThreadService();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunFirstMethod());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunSecondMethod());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Maybe this is not a good idea ...? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thx.

First attempt with Semaphores (not ok):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadService threadService = new ThreadService();

        Semaphore semaphoreFirstMethod = new Semaphore(2, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            semaphoreFirstMethod.WaitOne();
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunFirstMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphoreFirstMethod.Release());
        }

        Semaphore semaphoreSecondMethod = new Semaphore(2,2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            semaphoreSecondMethod.WaitOne();
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunSecondMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphoreSecondMethod.Release());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here are the results:

```
   2018-08-25 15:34:17.7259 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:17.7259 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:19.7691 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:19.7691 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:21.7775 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:21.7775 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:21.7775 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:23.8053 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:23.8053 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:34:25.8211 INFO RunSecondMethod()
```

After @mjwills suggested to post the code with sempahores, I've figured out that I'm not doing something as it should be,
Second Implementation with semaphores:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadService threadService = new ThreadService();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                semaphore.WaitOne();
                Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunFirstMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphore.Release());
            }
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                semaphore.WaitOne();
                Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunSecondMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphore.Release());
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Second results (which are ok for me):

```
    2018-08-25 15:36:01.0845 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:01.0855 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:02.0863 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:03.0783 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:03.1386 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:03.1386 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:04.0938 INFO RunFirstMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:05.0877 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:05.1547 INFO RunSecondMethod()
2018-08-25 15:36:05.1677 INFO RunFirstMethod()
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I fail to understand your requirements :/

Comment: What your method will do actually? Calculation, loading data from some external resources (database, webservice etc)?

Comment: @Fabio loading data from external resources processing them and publishing

Comment: For loading data from external resources you don't need multi-threading. You can load data "simultaneously" on one thread (When you load data your threads do nothing - only waiting for responses - which will be waste of resources. Then for processing data you can use [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Comment: @Fabio yes, but in my case each thread is actually independent, Each of them will load, process different data. Each will do specific work for specific client

Comment: @mjwills I've updated the question so you can see the semaphore approach. Thx for pointing out that something is wrong, now it seems to be ok and the results are as expected for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to all for the help. I've did the solution by running two tasks. I needed 2 methods to run in parallel and to control the number of threads per each)
The number of threads is controlled by the semaphores.
Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadService threadService = new ThreadService();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunFirstMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphore.Release());
        }
    });

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            Task t = Task.Run(() => threadService.RunSecondMethod()).ContinueWith(s => semaphore.Release());
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add some dispatching logic which would decide which method to execute basing on a thread logical index:

```
var threadService = new ThreadService();
Parallel.For(
    0, 6,
    index =>
    {
        if (index < 4)
            threadService.RunFirstMethod();
        else
            threadService.RunSecondMethod();
    });
```

This however doesn't guarantee that a method will be exclusively executed on the same core. To achieve this you need specify thread-CPU affinity which is bit tricky for .NET because it uses its own threads on top of the system threads which are only threads the CPU affinity can be applied to. Here is [good article](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2010/03/08/Running_NET_threads_on_selected_processor_cores) which explains how to get this done with external calls.

Comment: yes, I've started with that approach in the beginning but I never know how many tasks I'll need to have for the methods maybe for the first one 10 tasks, and for the second 200 tasks and it was a tricky and I want at same time 3 tasks of first method and 4 tasks of second method to be executed (just for example). I've updated the question doing it with semaphores. (the second approach) and it is achieving what I actually wanted